# Dos tablas o una para entidades similares

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, backend, rendimiento

¿Dos tablas o una con id para diferenciar los registros?

Hola, tengo una duda, espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo una tabla para personas físicas y otra tabla para personas morales, ambas son personas para la lógica de negocios y tienen algunos campos en común. Mi pregunta es ¿qué es más conveniente en términos de mejores prácticas y rendimiento? ¿hacer dos tablas (una para cada tipo de persona) o una tabla con un campo de identificación para diferenciarlas por tipo de persona?

Al final ocuparé el id de las personas como clave foránea en otra tabla. Al tener dos tablas tengo que hacer una tabla más para hacer esta referencia. Algo como eso:

[physical_person]

- id
- name
- rfc

[legal_person]

- id
- business_name
- rfc

[person]

- id
- id_physical_person
- id_legal_person

[hit]

- id
- id_person

Si solo utilizo una tabla quedaría así:

[person]

- id
- name
- business_name
- rfc
- id_person_type

[hit]

- id
- id_person

Puse algunos campos como ejemplo, pero en realidad cada tabla tiene un poco más de 20 y coinciden entre las tablas con aproximadamente 10.

Los registros que puede tener cada tipo de persona probablemente no lleguen al millón.

Se usará SQLAlchemy para manipular los datos y se mostrarán en una interfaz con Angular.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Saludos. Crea tu esquema a tu lógica y experiencia; luego de decirte en una tabla o por separado te pueden salir más dudas e incluso impactar a tu forma de trabajo. Suerte.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Voy a optar por las dos tablas porque voy a utilizar un ORM y creo que va a ser más fácil identificar cuando esté tratando con personas físicas o personas morales en lugar de tener una sola entidad de personas. De nueva cuenta, agradezco mucho tu comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que tu pregunta se refiere al tema llamado normalización.

No hay una respuesta que sirva en todas las situaciones sobre si se mejora el rendimiento o no, dependerá de analizar muchos factores. Si tu esquema empieza a crecer y tiene que interactuar entre una gran cantidad de tablas que pueden complejizar la situación es diferente a si tu sistema es estático y pequeño.

Acá puedes encontrar tips e información útil para tomar una decisión.

[Normalización de bases de datos - WIKIPEDIA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos)

[Diseño de base de datos con desnormalización - IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/es/db2-for-zos/11?topic=design-database-denormalization)

[Oracle normalization tips - Inglés](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_table_normalization.htm)

Comment: Gracias Claudio, no sabía que se podían desnormalizar las bases de datos, siempre pensé que debía normalizarlas para mejorar el diseño. Saludos!